# Alternatives to Stackexchange Philosophy

Tags: discussion

Does anybody know any good alternatives to this site? I don't like how this channel is being moderated and the fact that your freedom of speech is not guaranteed.

For a number of reasons I would like to find a place in which people are more tolerant towards questions that intellectually challenge you, in which as long as your questions are respectful and interesting they are respected and not closed by ego-maniac people with PhDs and you don't have to follow a Pro USA-capitalism ideology.

**UPDATE**
As said by one of the moderators I would like to find a platform in which Philosophical ideas can be discussed. Does anybody have any recommendations?

Comment: You clearly are the respectful and reasonable part of the discussion here, are you? StackExchange is about *knowledge*, so **speculation** (capitalist, socialist, or otherwise) is a bad fit even if you are intellectually unchallenged by anything but intuition/speculation. AFAIR, there is a fair amount of (unchallenged) questions and answers neutrally discussing Marxism, anarchy, and other doctrines critical of capitalism as well. So please, watch your tone.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking speculation and thought experiments are necessary to attain knowledge. This channels proves how wrong western philosophy is and how the ego of the "philosophers" specially the ones with PhDs intercedes with truth and the search for it. “Doubt is the origin of wisdom” ― René Descartes

Comment: Exactly, they are necessary to *attain* knowledge. Since StackExchange is *about* (existing) knowledge (experts answering your questions) and not about *obtaining original knowledge*, they are misplaced here. The whole point of a Q & A format is to have *the* answer to the question and not a bunch of open questions soliciting speculative responses. Nobody restricts the subject-matter of questions and answers here, only the *mode* of questioning and answering. I am well aware that this does not suit the *practice* of philosophy well, alas this does not change the facts.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking you have plenty of examples here tagged as "thought-experiments" that have been discussed. Some specific questions asking for authors or references have been closed and downvoted and even deleted. Speculation can lead to logic and logic to truth. Facts or objective truth are something to speculate about with logic an critical thinking skills in ordinary philosophy forums.

Comment: The thought-experiments discussed usually are variants of well-established ones discussed countless times in the literature. Let's face it: The aspiration of speculatively obtaining new and original "facts" or "objective truth" in philosophy is hubris. You may find new ways to express something, but sincere studies of philosophy show you that there *always* have been others thinking and writing materially the same. Also, Philosophy.SE is StackExchange first and foremost, not a philosophy "forum" for exchanging philosophical ideas.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking My last question suits all your premises. Let's see how long until it's closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/philosophy/

I don't know if it is better than this site, but it seems to be similar and a popular alternative.

You could stay here. Part of participating in discussions is using language to interact with real people. If a question is closed, find another way to approach the subject. Don't worry about it except to learn from the experience and try again.

Anyone may ask or answer questions here. No one has to be an expert to do either. No one has to have a PhD in philosophy. I don't and I write often. That doesn't mean everyone will like the questions or answers that I offer.

Comment: I disagree with you on the closing question part. To me it's more like censorship and not everybody is trained to be a judge. Some of my questions specially related to 9/11 are not closed but deleted! To some people it's just a nut-case "conspiracy theory" to me it's just a revolution of the mind just like relativity or evolution. Time will tell... Thanks for your advice I have already found another more suitable forum to my needs.

Comment: @PbxMan Best wishes. I hope things work out for you on that forum. The people here who are making judgments can be *anyone* with adequate reputation and who want to participate. No one need have any training or experience. Those interested in being active here also change over time.  So what is accepted or not today may be different from what is accepted or not a year from now.